# How do I write to NTFS drives in OS X?

Tags: macos, ntfs

What is the best, easiest, preferably cheapest way to make OS X write to NTFS-formatted drives in Mac OS X?

Comment: If that NTFS filestore happens to be a Seagate harddrive, then use their [free version](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/) of the [Paragon NTFS Drivers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302886/136150) (for OSX 10.10+).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Updated at May 2015, with current solutions.

**Free solutions**

[FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io) - Successor to MacFUSE

[NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/)
Requires a build from source for anything newer than 2010. Last "pre-built" version linked from [NTFS-3G for Mac OS X 2010.10.2](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html). You can build it from source using homebrew in the other answers.

**Paid solutions**

[Paragon NTFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)

[Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/)

---

MacFuse is abandonware and hasn't been updated since 2009.

Comment: Fuse for OS X and NTFS-3G must be installed together. Full installation is tricky on El Capitan: See my answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213575/62697

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is nearly a link-only answer, so I've downvoted it. Currently both https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106589/write-in-ntfs-using-mavericks?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152661/write-to-ntfs-formated-drives-on-yosemite?noredirect=1&lq=1 are marked as a duplicate of this question, but unfortunately this (currently accepted) answer is not the highest quality in my opinion.

Comment: MacFuse doesn't seem to be abandonware. It's being maintained

Comment: @MuhsinFatih However not as open source

Answer (score 34):

### Newer macOS

This answer is for latest compatibility for **macOS 13 Ventura and macOS 14 Sonoma**.

1. Install [macFUSE](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse) with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as follow:

   ```
   brew install macfuse
   ```
2. Install [NTFS-3G](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) with Homebrew as follow:

   ```
   brew tap gromgit/homebrew-fuse
   brew install ntfs-3g-mac
   ```
3. Auto-mount NTFS volumes in read-write mode:

Link NTFS-3G to boot after temporary disabling System Integrity Protection, as follow:

```
* [reboot by holding <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to get in recovery mode]

        csrutil disable

* [reboot normally]

        sudo mount -uw /
        sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original
        sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs

* [reboot by holding <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to get in recovery mode]

        csrutil enable

* [reboot normally]
```

You will need to re-link manually (step 3) each year when you upgrade macOS (10.11 → 10.12 → 10.13 → 10.14 → 10.15 → 11 → 12 → 13 → 14 ...)

See also the following wiki page which is the installation documentation: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

---

### Older macOS and troubleshooting

This answer is for compatibility for **OS X 10.11 El Capitan**, **macOS 10.12 Sierra**, **macOS 10.13 High Sierra**, **macOS 10.14 Mojave**.

It needs an update for Apple Silicon and Monterey and Big Sur and Catalina so *proceed with caution*

1. Install osxfuse (3.x.x) from [GitHub](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases). Or install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as follow:

   ```
   brew install --cask osxfuse
   ```
2. Install [NTFS-3G](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) with Homebrew as follow:

   ```
   brew install ntfs-3g
   ```
3. Proceed to step 3 in "Newer macOS" answer above.

Additional steps if solution does not work:

- try to install ntfs-3g again

  ```
   brew install ntfs-3g
  ```
- it warns that it installed but not linked, try to link again:

  ```
   brew link ntfs-3g
  ```
- it fails and prints dry-run command which will show files to remove:

  ```
   brew link --overwrite --dry-run ntfs-3g
  ```
- remove these files with sudo ('Would remove:' is for English console)

  ```
   brew link --overwrite --dry-run ntfs-3g | grep -vF 'Would remove:' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo rm
  ```
- try to link again and get permission error on creation /usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g. brew prevents running with sudo so prepare directory for README:

  ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g
   sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g
  ```
- run `brew link` again... success.
- reboot your Mac and allow system extension to load in System Preferences as error box suggests.

Comment: For linking issue with homebrew, maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422345/installed-just-not-linked ; also, try brew uninstall ntfs-3g.

Comment: Those who don't want to link it during startup and just wanna give it a go, you can try this. 
"After installing NTFS-3G you can manually mount NTFS volumes in read-write mode by executing the following commands in Terminal. Replace /dev/disk1s1 with the actual NTFS partition you want to mount. You can find the partition name using diskutil list.

sudo mkdir /Volumes/NTFS
sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other"
From https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

Answer (score 19):

I tested this on Mountain lion and it is free and you don't need to reboot. It uses OS X's native NTFS drivers.

1. Plug-in your device
2. Write in Terminal `diskutil list` and look for IDENTIFIER where TYPE is Windows_NTFS.

   [image]

   In this case it is `disk1s1`
3. Then run the following:

   ```
   diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s1
   cd /Volumes
   mkdir Elements
   sudo mount -w -t ntfs -o rw,nobrowse /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/Elements
   open /Volumes/Elements
   ```

Comment: I tried this on 10.8.4 and a 10.8 VM, but I couldn't get it to work. I got an error like `Read-only file system` when I for example tried to run `mkdir /Volumes/HD-HCU2/aa`. Is there some reason why you used `nobrowse`?

Comment: You are creating the folder on wrong path. You should create the folder under `/Volumes`.

Comment: `nobrowse` are needed to make ntfs writable.

Comment: +1, Be aware that this feature is not complete and well-tested. It's not enabled by default for some reason. Worth mentioning that the force-write-enabled driver simply damaged an NTFS volume while I was playing with it.

Comment: So there is a capability within OS X to mount NTFS for read and write support. But this is disabled. Is there a way to do a 'defaults write' to activate this feature?

Comment: I've added a warning about this method not being safe. This old crappy Apple NTFS driver has been there forever, it's been known forever that it can be forced to be RW, and it's been known forever that it's not stable by any means.

Comment: I come up with this utility that automate the instructions https://github.com/rodfersou/osx-ntfs-rw

Comment: This is not working on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 for me as the mount command returns the `Read-only file system` error, even the mount point folder is under `/Volumes`. The `-w` flag in the mount command is irrelevant as the man page indicates that it's specific to NFS but not NTFS.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution would be to use [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) and [NTFS-3G for MacFUSE](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/), though as of this post only [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) (
~$35 USD) and PARAGON Software [NTFS for OS X](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)  v.9.0 ($19.95 USD) support 10.7. You can grab the [source for free](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) from Tuxera for free, however.

As of OS X 10.6 you can natively enable NTFS support, though your mileage may vary. Follow [this writeup](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382) by Mac OS X Hints if you're interested but I'd use the MacFUSE method over this one. Keep in mind that neither of these methods are fully supported.

Comment: Just to note—I've had [some problems with NTFS-3G & Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20037/ntfs-3g-unmounts-ntfs-partitions-because-it-did-not-receive-signal-in-15-seconds) lately, which might be because the OS X binary is a bit outdated (2010.10.2 versus [2011.4.12](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/))

Comment: Paragon NTFS for Mac v9 IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH LION. Double-click the package gives "The operation couldn't be completed"

Comment: any disadvantages of using Tuxera NTFS for the new macbook pro retina ?

Comment: MacFUSE got replaced by [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/)

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do a one-time mount using ntfs-3g (coeur's answer but for one time use).  This way doesn't require you to boot into safe mode or use csrutil at all.

NB: using `ntfs-3g` this way is rumored to be "safer" for write access than the built-in `ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse` mount option:

Install latest osxfuse (3.x.x) from https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases. Or install it from Homebrew with:

```
brew cask install osxfuse
```

Install latest NTFS-3GNTFS-3G from Homebrew (https://brew.sh/Homebrew), as follow:

```
brew install ntfs-3g
```

One time mount (replace disk1s1 with your values, discoverable by running a `mount` command after inserting the disk, you'll see a line like

`/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/SomeNtfsDrive (ntfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners`) grab the `disk1s1`:

```
 diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s1
 sudo mkdir /Volumes/my_writable_ntfs
 sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/my_writable_ntfs -olocal -oallow_other
```

You'll get a popup "system extension blocked" click "Open Security Preferences" and click "Allow" next to the developer name (Benjamin Fleischer). If you can't click the allow button, see [here](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1017).

Run the command again after clicking allow.  It'll be good until you reboot.  or manually dismount it.

For more details and instructions on making it permanent, see https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

Comment: I come up with this utility that automate the instructions https://github.com/rodfersou/osx-ntfs-rw

Answer (score 6):

Can't say that using MacFUSE and NTFS-3G for MacFUSE is the easiest way, but they are free and that's great!:) I've used them for about a year until bought 500GB external Seagate HDD and got Paragon NTFS for Mac driver for free from Seagate site: http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/. Works stable for a month, no problems happened yet. Anybody knows, will users of Seagate HDDs get free NTFS driver upgrade for new OS X when Apple will release it?

Comment: does the seagate version of paragon 14 work for drives other than seagate?

Answer (score 5):

Before we start. Make sure your external name label is **ONE** word.
That means there is no space in between.

my disk = **WRONG**

my_disk **or** my-disk **or** mydisk = **CORRECT**

## Now

1. Open Terminal [<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+"terminal"]
2. Type: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
3. In nano, type: `LABEL=my_disk none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse` Note: **my_disk** is **your** disk name
4. To save and exit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. **[optional]** For ease of access, we create a sym-link to desktop: In terminal -> `sudo ln -s /Volumes ~/Desktop/Volumes`

## Later

When you don't need it anymore. It is as simple as:

In terminal `sudo rm /etc/fstab`

Comment: Removing `/etc/fstab` is only an option if it doesn't contain any other important entries

Comment: @AFwcxx, The Label **can** contain spaces, you just have to substitute `\040` for the ' ' (space).  See example in `man fstab`: `LABEL=The\040Volume\040Name\040Is\040This none msdos ro`

Comment: This and [osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/) helped me a lot. All I had to do was unmount my drive, edit the fstab file, create a sym-link and that's it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for **macOS BigSur**:

The big difference with [previous answer by Cœur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213575/364260):

we need to turn off cryptographic verification (See [Big Sur’s Signed System Volume: added security protection](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/)) with `csrutil authenticated-root disable` in step 3.2 and `bless` to create a snapshot in step 4.

1. Install macFUSE from [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io) or `brew --cask install osxfuse`
2. Install ntfs-3g with `brew install gromgit/fuse/ntfs-3g-mac` or try [other options to install ntfs-3g](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422521/cant-install-ntfs-3g-on-macos-bigsur)
3. Disable SIP(System Integrity Protection)

   3.1 Reboot Mac into Recovery Mode by rebooting and holding down Command+R

   3.2 Utilities > Terminal:

   `csrutil disable`(enable it after the whole process)

   `csrutil authenticated-root disable` (It cannot be enabled after updating /sbin/mount_ntfs)

   3.3 Reboot in normal mode
4. Update /sbin/mount_ntfs

   4.1 Get the root disk by `mount`, if `/dev/disk1s5s1 on /`  is returned, your root disk is `/dev/disk1s5`

   4.2 update and **create snapshot**

   ```
   DISK_PATH=/dev/disk1s5
   MOUNT_PATH=~/mount
   mkdir $MOUNT_PATH
   sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs $DISK_PATH $MOUNT_PATH
   sudo mv $MOUNT_PATH/sbin/mount_ntfs        $MOUNT_PATH/sbin/mount_ntfs.original
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs $MOUNT_PATH/sbin/mount_ntfs

   sudo bless --folder $MOUNT_PATH/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot
   ```
5. Reboot and enable SIP with command: `csrutil enable`

Reference:
[NTFS write in macOS BigSur using osxfuse and ntfs-3g](https://shivang-iitk.medium.com/ntfs-write-in-macos-bigsur-using-osxfuse-and-ntfs-3g-3f3253ba2365)

Comment: How does this differ from provious answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213575/237

Comment: For macOS BigSur, the big difference is that we need to execute `csrutil authenticated-root disable` and `bless` to create a snapshot

Comment: In that case please note that BigSur does differ and note the extra bit in the answer