# Has Lion Native NTFS read/write support improved?

Tags: macos, ntfs

I know [about the other third-party options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-lion) out there, this is more to do with the native stuff that comes bundled from Apple.  For years Snow Leopard has had notoriously bad NTFS read-write support hence it was disabled by default.  We could [enable it like this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382), but it was dangerous at best.  So, has this improved in Lion, or is this still a neglected dangerous feature?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen any credible reports that NTFS write support has improved with Lion. It was in Snow Leopard and still is disabled natively.

---

As, it's not supported by Apple, getting a good third party plug in to enable that feature is as mandatory with Lion as it was with Snow Leopard.

Comment: You can still just remount it as rw unless its dirty flag is set (it is if it wasn't unmounted properly last time). I never had problems, in my opinion you don't have to spend money on a third party plugin.