# How to remount an internal drive as read-write in mountain lion

Tags: macos, mount

Suddenly a secondary drive with HFS+ partition changed from read-write to read-only. How can I use the mount command to reverse it in mountain lion?

Answer (score 18):

Try using `mount -u -w`:

```
sudo mount -u -w /Volumes/YourDriveName
```

`-u` modifies the status of an already mounted filesystem. `-w` mounts a filesystem as read-write.

Comment: `mount_hfs: Invalid argument`.

Comment: If it's ntfs you may need a few more params than that: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x and also you may need to unmount then remount to avoid "Read Only Drive" message...

Comment: Is there any way to revoke write access after doing this?

Comment: You’d have to unmount the drive and re-mount it as read-only.

Answer (score 7):

The answers in this thread did not work for me, but this did:

```
  sudo mount -u -o rw /Volumes/VolName
```

Comment: same error as above for me

Comment: Somewhat strangely, I had to run above command twice for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes when a drives filesystem is corrupted. Run Disk Utility and check the filesystem and drive for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Occassionaly when this happens to me I need to use the disk utility included with OSX to verify and repair the disk. Any attempts to use `mount -u -w /Volume/NIKON-S9700` will fail with this error:

```
$ sudo mount -u -w "/Volumes/NIKON-S9700"
mount_msdos: /dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/NIKON-S9700: Permission denied
```

You can tell that the disk is mounted read-only like so:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/NIKON-S9700 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

**NOTE:** Notice the "read-only" in the output above for device `/dev/disk2s1`.

Once I run a repair disk from Disk Utility the drive when mounted shows up like this:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/NIKON-S9700 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

Incidentally the repair disk button might sometimes show up as grayed out. I typically have to unmount and remount the disk with Disk Utility running in order to get this button to show up as clickable.

#### screenshot of Disk Utility with mounted SD Card

[image: ss#1]

Answer (score 1):

This was silly, but after a bunch of troubleshooting, for me the problem was that I was dealing with an sd card that had its lock switch turned on.  I ejected the disk, toggled the switch, re-inserted it, and it was back to read+write.