# How to unblock an NTFS volume from mounting?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

Today I was no longer able to mount an NTFS volume (external HDD) that I use on a daily basis. I had the "Unformatted disk" error, prompting me to initialize (reformat) it.

After scanning the disk using Disk Drill, I understood that my content were still there and intact. However, it would have taken ~20hrs to salvage content (2TB HDD) and directories would have been lost, as well as most filenames (and some videos got corrupted).

I bumped across a similar issue in this forum ([External Hard Drive Won't Mount](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268998/external-hard-drive-wont-mount)) and I found a solution using TestDisk. However, I wasn't able to publish my answer as I am a newbie (not enough rep) so I'll post it here, hoping it will help others.

Comment: Hi Delek, I've merged this question with the question you linked to so your answer has been moved there, and unprotected the question for the future. Thanks for your contribution!