# How do I Create a Macro or Shortcut to run a Command Sequence Terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount, ntfs

The following was posted by Codler as [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97360/145449) to a question of read/write difficulties on NTFS drive which worked perfectly.

My question is, is there a way for a noob like me to create a shortcut method of running these steps in Terminal instead of typing it in each time I want to mount the drive?

> 1. Plug-in your device
> 2. Write in Terminal `diskutil list` and look for IDENTIFIER where TYPE is Windows_NTFS.
>
>    In this case it is `disk1s1`
> 3. Then run the following:
>
>    ```
>    diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s1
>    cd /Volumes
>    mkdir Elements
>    sudo mount -w -t ntfs -o rw,nobrowse /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/Elements
>    open /Volumes/Elements
>    ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the hard drive to show up in the Finder? I had a similar need in the past, and solved it by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=<disk label> <mount point> ntfs auto,nobrowse
```

where:

- `<mount point>` is the directory where you want to mount the hard drive, in your case `/Volumes/Elements`. I'd recommend, though, that you mount the drive elsewhere to prevent name collisions, as `/Volumes` is used by the Finder to mount removable drives. Let's say you choose `/MyVolumes`.
- `<disk label>` is the hard drive name as it appears in the Finder, I guess `Elements`.

So, in your case, the line should read:

```
LABEL=Elements /MyVolumes/Elements ntfs auto,nobrowse
```

Now, `/etc/fstab` is a **system file** so care must be taken not to break anything:

1. Open Applications>Utilities>Terminal.
2. In Terminal, type:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /MyVolumes/Elements
   ```

   to create the folder `/MyVolumes/Elements`.
3. Now type:

   ```
   sudo cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
   sudo cp /etc/fstab ~/Desktop/fstab.txt
   sudo chown $(whoami) ~/Desktop/fstab.txt
   ```

   Type your password when asked.

   These commands: 1) create a copy of `/etc/fstab` you can fallback to if anything goes wrong, 2) copy `/etc/fstab` to your Desktop, 3) change ownership of the copy on your Desktop so that you can edit it.
4. Switch to the Finder, double click `fstab.txt` on your Desktop and add at the bottom of the file (the file is probably empty) the following:

   ```
   LABEL=Elements /MyVolumes/Elements ntfs auto,nobrowse
   ```

   Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to close the editor.
5. Back to Terminal, type:

   ```
   sudo mv -f ~/Desktop/fstab.txt /etc/fstab
   ```

   to overwrite `/etc/fstab` with your modified version.
6. Plug in your drive. Does it work? **Great!** It doesn't? Something went wrong... type in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo mv -f /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab
   ```

   to restore the original `/etc/fstab`.