# NTFS write not working any more after update

Tags: macos, ntfs

I searched for solutions to make OS X write NTFS disks, and found this one;
[How do I write to NTFS drives in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x)
It worked like a charm, until I updated my mac recently. Now it does not want to write to the NTFS disk anymore even with the nobrowse options. But nobrowse is still applied since the disk does not appear on my Desktop.
The writing is just disabled.
Any reasons why the most recent version of OS X 10.8.5 does not allow to write to NTFS even with that uncomfortable way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the first rule of computer troubleshooting, which basically says that if you installed something (application, driver, etc...) and then that functionality stops working after an O/S upgrade then reinstall the app's latest version.

Also good to double check that it is compatible with your version of the O/S ;-)

Comment: Well, it´s basically the OS update itself with a native driver which is not enabled by default, dont think it´s a good idea (or even possible) to revert those OS updates

Answer (score 0):

Actually OS X allows native reading of NTFS disks, just not writing.

Comment: Did you see the link? It allowed writing (and I am pretty sure there has to be a way enable it again), but now it seems to be disabled.