# NTFS External drive issue in Mac 10.9

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, external-disk, ntfs

Earlier i was able to access the NTFS formatted External hard drive in my Mac 10.9 as read only device.

While trying to make the external NTFS drive writable i screwed up by unmouting it

[this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x)

> diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s1

Later when i tried mounting it again it failed

> diskutil mount
>   Volume on disk1s1 failed to mount

[image: Error Message When i connect my External Hard drive]

Answer (score 1):

Following the unmount you should also eject the disc before unplugging it.

```
diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s2    
diskutil eject /dev/disk1s2
```

Alternatively you could use the usual methods: eject via finder, via dragging the drive icon into the waste bin, or with third-party apps like Alfred or Launchbar.