# What "defaults" command is used to enable NTFS write support in OS X

Tags: macos, defaults, ntfs

I remember long time back I came across some terminal command (something like: `defaults write...`) to enable ntfs write support on OS X. When I am searching for the command now I can see only either of the below options:

1. Using 3rd party software like Fuse
2. Using /etc/fstab

I had enabled ntfs support without any 3rd party software or modifying /etc/fstab. But I don't remamber the command now. It starts something like `defaults write...`. Can anyone help me on this?

To cross verify my memory, I checked my system and I don't have any 3rd party software for the same installed and do not have anything in /etc/fstab but I am able to write to NTFS.

Currently I am looking for the old command I used so that I configure the same in another mac.

OS Version - Yosemite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write to NTFS drives in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the said post. That post doesn't talk about the defaults command I am looking for.

Answer (score -3):

In ElCapitan there is no fstab file, and I doubt very much if there is a possibility to write NTFS without a third party driver such as Tuxeira NTFS  or  Paragon NTFS.

Comment: The OS X NTFS driver does indeed have write support. The only way I know of to enable it is to use the fstab, which does indeed exist at /etc/fstab, and I don't believe was ever a folder.

Comment: The etc/fstab file [not folder, as rightly said, may not already exist, but is easy enough to create.

Comment: The fstab file simple needs to be created.