# How to enable NTFS 3G?

Tags: mac, macos, homebrew, external-disk, ntfs

It is a common issue Mac users, when you try open NTFS external storage you allowed only read mode. And of course there are some solution. One of them it is NTFS 3G - free alternative.

I followed instructions

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

I set up FUSE then I set up Brew and eventually I set up NTFS 3G

But because lack of experience in Mac and English I can't understand what I need to do after all

According to link

> Even though you have installed NFTS-3G, newly connected NTFS volumes will still be auto-mounted in read-only mode. To change this you need to replace Apple's NTFS mount tool /sbin/mount_ntfs with the one provided by NTFS-3G.

It says that I need to replace Apple's NTFS mount tool with the one provided by NTFS-3G...

How to do it? I don't know any tools provided by NTFS-3G...

Please help me to finish installing process

**Edit**

I found this two commands to solve my issue

```
sudo mv "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs" "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs.orig"
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs"
```

After I execute first command I got follow output

```
mv: rename /Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs.orig: No such file or directory
```

After I execute second command I got follow output

```
ln: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/sbin/mount_ntfs: No such file or directory
```

**Edit2**

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ sudo mv "/sbin/mount_ntfs" "/sbin/mount_ntfs.orig"

Password:

mv: rename /sbin/mount_ntfs to /sbin/mount_ntfs.orig: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: The directions are on the linked page in your question. You need to read that page completely and follow the directions.

Comment: @user3439894 If I understand you correctly you said about two commands that was mentioned little bellow (I edited my question according your comment) . Did you mean that?

Comment: In the commands swap "Macintosh HD" for whatever your Mac's system hard drive is called. Or try the command without "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" in them. For example, `sudo mv "/sbin/mount_ntfs" "/sbin/mount_ntfs.orig"
`.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I tried but anyway got bad massage (added in question)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Which version of the operating system are you running?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Seirra 10.12.2

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You'll need to turn System Integrity Protection (SIP) off first then. There are instructions in the document you linked above on how to do that. Remember to turn it back on afterwards.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan did you mean this line `To replace /sbin/mount_ntfs with the version provided by NTFS-3G you will need to reboot your Mac in recovery mode before proceeding.` ?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Yes here is more detailed information on disabling System Integrity Protection on your Mac. http://imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I am a little worry about it. But there is some questions if you know of course 1) I need to do it every time when I need to write NTFS ? 2) Is there more safety way to do it?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You only need to do it once. When you install a system update from Apple you might need to run those Terminal commands again though.

Comment: Using the built-in NTFS support is much easier. If you want a nifty graphical utility you can install [Mounty](http://enjoygineering.com/mounty/).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto yes! You save my life)) it is work very nice. If you publish as answer I will accept it

Comment: I come up with this utility that automate the steps in the website https://github.com/rodfersou/osx-ntfs-rw

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Alternative approach - may be unstable or cause data corruption

While you can use NTFS-3G for accessing NTFS drives, it should be noted that **recent versions of macOS support writing to NTFS drives natively.** This option however is hidden from the GUI and [you'd normally need the terminal](http://enjoygineering.com/mounty/) to do it:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk3s1 ~/ntfs-volume
```

Uwe Hollatz created [Mounty](http://enjoygineering.com/mounty/), which is a nifty tool to automate this process. It sits in your taskbar waiting for NTFS drives to be detected.

[image: Mounty screenshot]

If you use Homebrew, install it with the following command:

```
brew cask install mounty
```

Otherwise, download the DMG from its website.

Comment: Good find. I went with this approach as I'm new to mac and I don't want to mess with the system integrity protection to enable ntfs-3g

Comment: **A WORD OF WARNING** if you are considering using write mode with the built-in macOS NTFS driver. I added an entry to my /etc/fstab to enable this (`LABEL=Stuff none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`) and had constant problems with FS corruption. 100s of files and entire directories would sometimes disappear and the only way to fix it was to reboot into Windows and run CHKDSK /f on the volume. **TL;DR: I would not recommend using rw mode on the built in macOS NTFS driver as the write support is not stable.**

Comment: @Gondrup eh, actually a couple of times I had to use *the NTFS data recovery software I developed myself* on drives used that way. :D

Comment: Latest brew command: `brew install --cask mounty`

Answer (score 2):

Operations need to be done in a particular state: by disabling System Integrity Protection. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213575/62697

Here is the relevant part:

> 3. Link NTFS-3G to boot after temporary disabling System Integrity Protection, as follow:
>
> [reboot by holding CMD+R to get in recovery mode]
>
> ```
>    csrutil disable
> ```
>
> [reboot normally]
>
> ```
>    sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original
>    sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
> ```
>
> [reboot by holding CMD+R to get in recovery mode]
>
> ```
>    csrutil enable
> ```
>
> [reboot normally]

Note: If the `mv` command fails with *No such file or directory*, then it's not a problem, just ignore it. The important command is the `ln` command.