# mount NTFS for read/write failed, it worked before upgrading to 10.12.4

Tags: hard-drive, macos, filesystem, mount, ntfs

I was able to mount NTFS drives for both read and write in OS X 10.12.3. But in 10.12.4, it failed

In this example, I used the OS X native NTFS driver. (I used NTFS-3G on Mac before but it was too slow )

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk2s1 /Users/somebody/Desktop/tmp
```

Here's the error:

```
mount_ntfs: /dev/disk2s1 on /Users/somebody/Desktop/tmp: Read-only file system
```

But actually there is nothing in folder `tmp`

I don't know whether it's only me who has this error or everyone has the same issue after upgrading OS X to 10.12.4

Do you know how to enable it?

Comment: I [use Mounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266158/198820) almost daily. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this on 10.12.5 beta 5 and works OK. Beta 4 did not for me