# Can macOS High Sierra write to NTFS external drives?

Tags: high-sierra, ntfs

I have updated my MacBook Pro to macOS High Sierra 10.13. I previously used Paragon NTFS but now it's not working so I uninstalled it. However I noticed I can still read and write to my external hard drive without any other app.

Does this mean macOS High Sierra natively supports writing to NTFS external drives?

Comment: Have you tried Tuxera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable NTFS 3G?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266132/how-to-enable-ntfs-3g)

Comment: Paragon should be working if you upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

[You actually can](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/04/21/ntfs-write-support-on-os-x-mountain-lion/), and I just did it.

In short:

- note the label of your NTFS volume.
- edit `/etc/fstab` even if it doesn't exist, e.g. with `sudo vi /etc/fstab`
- Add this line for every NTFS volume: `LABEL="VOLUME_NAME_WITHOUT_QUOTES" none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`
- Re-plug your drive.

You will not see the drive in Finder's "Devices", because this option requires `nobrowse` to work, but it is mounted in `/Volumes/<ntfs_label>`

Answer (score 1):

By default, no, High Sierra only gives **read** support for NTFS. You can enable **write** support with popular free tools like FUSE + NTFS-3G.

Tested and working for free on High Sierra: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213575/62697

If you have Paragon or Tuxera, then you paid for a support and they will certainly help you to install the latest compatible version of their respective softwares.

Answer (score -2):

It's impossible to write to a NTFS drive on High Sierra without a third-party solution. You might have FUSE installed. To check if you have it installed go to the System Preferences and check if you see the FUSE icon there.

Comment: This answer makes no grammatical sense and I don't understand it.

Comment: If anyone has citatations to back up the assertion that this is impossible, please add them. If the answer is just wrong, it should be downvoted as opposed to deleted or flagged.