# Paragon Driver for Seagate

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk

I'm using MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion (OSX version 10.8.5) and I want to copy some data from the MacBook Pro to an NTFS formatted external hard drive.

I know that we can use the paid solution from Paragon by purchasing its driver. But I recently discovered that the DMG files from Paragon are provided for free on Seagate site here as well:

https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/software/paragon/

Has anyone used Paragon Driver from Seagate's site and can I use it safely? I'd like to make sure that this Driver works properly before actually using it. On one hand Paragon charges almost 20 USD for it and on the other hand, Seagate offers it for free.

Comment: Seagate's OEM (Paragon) NTFS driver has the same code base but works  with Seagate drives only.

Comment: @klanomath Why not add this as an answer? By doing that I can upvote it which in turn means the question can't be deleted by the OP in future (not saying they *would* do that, but at least this way we can preserve an answer that can help others). :)

Answer (score 2):

The NTFS drivers provided by Seagate are OEM versions of Paragon's *NTFS for Mac 14/15*.

They share the same code base but work with Seagate's external (and probably internal, if you replaced the original Apple HDD - **not tested**) drives only.

By buying an external Seagate drive you already paid for it in the price category of *dimes*.