# How can I get an NTFS partition to mount in macOS Mojave?

Tags: windows, partition, filesystem, hdd, mojave

[image]I have a external HDD with four different partitions on it. 3 out of 4 of them work flawlessly. Two partitions are running the macOS Extended filesystem, one is running good old fat32, with the last one being NTFS. I don't particularly need it mounted in macOS as it contains a bootable copy of Windows 10, or at least it used to.
I figure if I can mount the partition again and repair it or at least make a backup of it, I can get it working as a bootable partition once more. Here's the kicker, I can pull the partition up if I mount the drive in Windows 10 using a virtual machine. So why won't macOS recognize it?

Comment: macOS should be able to read (but not write) NTFS partition without needing any configuration or installation of software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write to NTFS drives in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x)

Comment: If the NTFS partition literally does not mount, it may have a problem. I'd plug it into a VM or actual Windows PC and run check disk on it. You won't be able to effect a repair *ON* macOS, only Windows as macOS does not have the ability (natively) to write to NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a third party software to mount NTFS portions on a mac like Paragon you need to go to system preferences - security & privacy - allow. Then choose your software to allow it access.