# Can't delete files and folder from external driver

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, permission

A completely Mac Newbie here. I just bought iMac 2021. I have Samsung SSD 1TB. And I can't delete Files or Folders, there is no option to delete.

I checked Get Info, it shows that I have Read and Write permission, but still I can't delete. I already googled and many posts suggested the third-party app `NTFS`. I downloaded the app, but I can't install it, because it is not compatible with Big Sur 11.5.1.

And I don't really want to format my SSD. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add in your question, external disk plugged at you Mac, the results of the terminal (Applications/Utility) command : `diskutil list external` ? If your disk is formatted NTFS you can try the utility Mounty : https://mounty.app

Comment: If the SSD is formatted as NTFS (which is the standard format for Windows) then you need a third party app for a Mac to delete files https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x/29158#29158 I would use one of the paid for options

Comment: As a note re googling. As an example I looked for things on AskDifferent most answers seem to be several years old - pre Mojave. The leading open source solution osxFuse/macFuse is now not open source

Comment: You should back up and re-format your SSD to APFS, even if you don't want to, if it's formatted NTFS (you can check in Disk Utility). Unless you are regularly using it on a Windows computer too, using NTFS is really sub-optimal on a Mac. But if it's not formatted NTFS, then you have a different problem. You know that in order to delete a file, you move it to the Trash, then empty the Trash, right? There is no "Delete" command on the Mac.

Comment: @ElhemEnohpi, yes my SSD is with NTFS Format. Thanks for the info. Then I have only one option: to format it to APFS. Just another silly question: If I format my SSD to APFS, can my LG OLED (with Android) read it?

Comment: I don't know about Android. I would assume it doesn't read APFS by default. There might be an app you can install, or not. I didn't say you have only one option, just that APFS is the best option if you will mainly use it on your Mac. You can also consider formatting the drive as exFAT if you need to use it on different operating systems. But APFS is best for Mac. Also, you don't say which NTFS app you tried. There are several. Paragon NTFS claims full compatibility with Big Sur.