# How can I use NTFS-3G installed using MacPorts?

Tags: macos, ntfs, mac, filesystem

After upgrading to Lion I'm having problem mounting NTFS drives in read/write mode. This is because [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) distributed by [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com) does not work with Lion.

At their suggestion I installed NTFS-3G using MacPorts. But as far as I can see it does not come with the usual preference pane. Its not enabled by default.

Do anyone know how to enable it? Or how to have the Preference Pane for the NTFS-3G from MacPorts?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: How's your Tuxera-provided NTFS-3G not working? By any chance, is it the [same reason I had struggled with](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20037/ntfs-3g-unmounts-ntfs-partitions-because-it-did-not-receive-signal-in-15-second)? Anyhow, the following link may help you (half of it helped me; it also has a MacPorts solution, which I can't properly test as I don't use MacPorts): http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTFS-3G from macports works perfectly fine. Check this detailed and well-written instruction: http://fernandofig.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f/

Answer (score 0):

Are you having issues mounting the NTFS volumes or just enabling the preference pane? If you need something to fix issues with mounting volumes, MacFuse should work; The last official build for Tuxera w/ OS X Lion can be downloaded here:

MacFuse 2.2: http://www.tuxera.com/mac/macfuse/MacFUSE-Tuxera-2.2.dmg

MacFuse: http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Comment: MacFUSE itself does not support any File System. I need NTFS-3G to work in Lion. As far as I can see they are yet to update that.