# Error "/dev/disk04 could not be mounted" when using NTFS-3G

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, startup

I use NTFS-3G in order to let myself read and write to my external hard drive in the correct format. My Mac is also bootcamped with Windows 7 on the other side.

Every time I startup my Mac I get an error saying that `/dev/disk04` could not be mounted, and it asks me to force or abort it.

Any ideas as to where the root of that problem might be? I think it may be related to Boot Camp.

Screenshot of when harddrive is plugged in:
[image]

Disk Util Output:
[image: Disk Util Output]

Comment: What's the output of `diskutil list`. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: how can i get the output? sorry im a Mac noob

Comment: Open your *Terminal.app* from Applications/Utilities, then enter the command `diskutil list`. Paste the output here in the editor, and don't forget to select the text and press `Ctrl-K` so the code is indented properly. Also, where and when *exactly* is the output shown? In a window in Finder?

Comment: Ok, will go grab my mac on my lunch in a couple hours and post the output then :) for now, the errors come up in an error window when i first logon to the machine. And it also comes up when i plug a USB device in such as my harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install NTFS-3G before or after installing Boot Camp? What solutions have you tried? See also:

[NTFS-3G unmounts NTFS partitions because it "did not receive signal in 15 seconds"—what signal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20037/ntfs-3g-unmounts-ntfs-partitions-because-it-did-not-receive-signal-in-15-second)

Comment: I'm pretty sure i added it after installing bootcamp if that creates an issue? 

Will try the fix on that link tonight, thanks!